# Starting a bounty

Tags: discussion

*Note*:  I couldn't find an explanation [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/)

I'd like to start a bounty (on a question that already received 4 answers) because:

"*The current answers do not contain enough detail..*"

Could you clarify these points?

- are the answers posted before the bounty is started excluded from the bounty?
- what happens if no new answer is posted, since the existing ones are not considered satisfactory?
- if there is more than one new good answer, can I divide the bounty between them? How do I do it?

**Update** after the answer

there are two more possibilities:

- what happens if I do not choose an answer?
- if I do not get any new answer and I post an answer, could I give to bounty to my own answer, even though this does not seem a great solution?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/

Comment: Please see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you may award the bounty to them as well.
2. By default, the bounty will not go to anyone.
3. No, you cannot divide the bounty and a user can only place one bounty per question.

Comment: Bounties will not be automatically awarded to preexisting answers. Please see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty